# trying to write a python regular expression to test just the first 9 characters match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to test True if my string "deed" will have "numbers or a blank" in the first 9 characters.

```
deed = "4472 0438 (N/A Online)$0"
```

I have tried the following, and several variations but always get back a True, when I try it on string that would should not return a True. So there is something I am doing wrong.

```
re.search("([\. 0-9]{0,6})",deed)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Sorry, brand new to Regex.. but learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regular expression

```
re.search("(^[ 0-9]{9})", deed)
```

The expression `"(^[ 0-9]{9})"` locates the string at beginning of the line and only match if the first 9 characters are either numubers or blanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just slice the first nine letters:

```
re.search(expr, deed[:9])
```